# Safari Full Screen display issue

Tags: css, video, safari, html5-video, fullscreen

I'm playing video on a website. The HTML5 `<video>` player is housed within a container div which positions it centrally. On most browsers when a user clicks full screen the video plays full screen in the browser without issue, but in Safari on OS the video is positioned half off the screen - I can only see the bottom 50%.

I suspect this is because the `<div>` container has CSS position:fixed and top:50% height:auto but I can't work out what I need to do to correct for this problem which only seems to occur in Safari.

I can't find any guidance on the web or evidence of anyone experiencing the same problem. Please help!

Website for reference: www.bigredbutton.tv - click a video to play it and then use the native full screen controls.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? Preferable as a stacksnippet right here in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the position to relative. It worked for one of the similar issue we faced.